# How to wrap <li> tags inside <ul> tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this and when I click the button inside `.items` class creates `<li>` elements like this:

```
<ul class="items">                                           <ul class="items">
    <li>img1</li>                                                <ul>
    <li>img2</li>       but i want every 3 <li>                      <li>img1</li>
    <li>img3</li>       to wrap them into a new <ul>                 <li>img2</li>
    <li>img4</li>       --------------------------------->           <li>img3</li>
    <li>img5</li>                                                </ul>
    <li>img6</li>                                                <ul>
    <li>img7</li>                                                    <li>img4</li>
    <li>img8</li>                                                    <li>img5</li>
    <li>img9</li>                                                    <li>img6</li>
    ...                                                          </ul>
</ul>                                                            ...
                                                             </ul>
```

index.php

```
<div class="articles" id="projects">
    <div class="items">
        <li class="item">

            <img class="proj-imgs" src="images/project-imgs/" data-field="projects" width="100%" height="100%">

        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="morebox">
        <a href="#" class="items-load">Load more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried these but with no luck:

First attempt:

```
$('.item').first().before("<ul>");
$('.item').last().after("</ul>");
```

Second attempt:

```
$( "<ul>" ).insertBefore( ".item:first-child" );
$( "</ul>" ).insertAfter( ".item:last-child" );
```

Third attempt:

```
$( ".items" ).prepend( "<ul>" );
$( ".items" ).append( "</ul>" );
```

Fourth attempt:

```
$(".items li").each(function() {
    $(this).find("li").wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
});
```

Fifth attempt:

```
$('.items li').each(function(){
    var uls = $('li', this);
    for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i+=3) {
        uls.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
    }
});
```

If you can help me I would appreciated!! If you want the other files such as the javascript file, php or database just tell me to add them! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your goal is invalid HTML. You have to wrap the `ul`s within `li`s, since `li` is the only valid element in `ul`.

Comment: first of all, ul -> ul is incorrect, the only tag allowed inside ul is li. you want ul -> li -> ul. see xhtml quick ref: http://www.w3.org/2010/04/xhtml10-strict.html#elem_ul

Comment: Why do you need to have more ULs? Is it necessary?

Comment: would making 3 `ul`s with class "items" suit you?

Comment: instead of trying to do this in jq why not just output the html inside PHP to start with, change your ajax or php file that is outputting the html when you click the button

Comment: The most of you are right so I changed class `.items` instead of `<ul>` I did it `<div>` so when I add the `ul` element before `<li>` it will be the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how DOM works, you can't insert opening and closing tags separately, you should insert an *element*. Also an `ul` can't be child of another `ul` element, it should be wrapped with a `li` element. For wrapping every 3 `li`s with `<li><ul></ul></li>` you can use the `wrapAll` method:

```
var $li = $('.items li');

for (var i = 0; i < $li.length; i+=3)
    $li.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<li><ul></ul></li>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzRNQ/

Comment: I tried this with no `<li>` e.g.(`.wrapAll('<ul></ul>');`) because I changed the code but not works.. basically when I run this it creates an `<ul>` element above all the dynamically generated `<li>` elements. So the markup is like that: `<div class="items"><ul></ul><li class="item">img1</li><li class="item">img2</li><li class="item">img3</li></div>`

Comment: I used the code in the console of firefox when the 3 `<li>` `.item` have already been generated and it worked...so something happens with synchronization maybe..I don't know...anyway thanks for your help. I'll mark this as correct!

Answer (score -1):

you need to put the new ul inside of an li, you cannot have ul -> ul, it is invalid markup.

so it would look like this

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

to create that in jquery would be like this

```
var mainUl = $("<ul>");
mainUl.append($("<li>").append($("<ul>").append("<li>").append("<li>").append("<li>")))
mainUl.append($("<li>").append($("<ul>").append("<li>").append("<li>").append("<li>")))
mainUl.append($("<li>").append($("<ul>").append("<li>").append("<li>").append("li>")))
```

you can take it a step further and add content to the 'li' elements as desired

Comment: This is not working..and I think that if worked it would be a bad practise!!

Comment: well according to this js fiddle it works just fine  http://jsfiddle.net/QBM5/dQAvL/2/, as for best bad practice, it was simply a backbone to help you out with your issue, not a decree of implementation.