# Wrap Li with Ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML built using Jquery. I now want to wrap the li inside a UL.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;width:100%;">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="CommonResults">
        <ul id="Common_container">
            <li class="commmonItems" id="CommonColumns">
            <input name="ColumnAlarm_group" disabled="" type="checkbox" checked="" value=" CommonAlarms "> CommonAlarms 
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACD">Acknowledged</li>
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACT">ActorID/OperatorID</li>
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACV">Active</li>
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ARD">Acknowledge Required</li>
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="COND">Condition</li>
                <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ENB">Enabled</li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should look like this after completion.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;width:100%;">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="CommonResults">
            <ul id="Common_container">
                <li class="commmonItems" id="CommonColumns">
                <input name="ColumnAlarm_group" disabled="" type="checkbox" checked="" value=" CommonAlarms "> CommonAlarms 
                    <ul><!-- After change -->
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACD">Acknowledged</li>
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACT">ActorID/OperatorID</li>
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ACV">Active</li>
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ARD">Acknowledge Required</li>
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="COND">Condition</li>
                        <li class="columnItem"><input name="Column_Group" type="checkbox" value="ENB">Enabled</li>
                    <ul><!-- After Change -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help or direction in getting the desired out come.Needs to be done using JavaScript/JQuery as I can't hard code this. Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044648/how-to-wrap-li-tags-inside-ul-tags) should answer your question.

Comment: You can't start with invalid html ... `<li>` is not a valid child of `<li>`. This is an XY Problem. How does this get generated as invalid html in the first place? You need to fix it there

Comment: How do you want to achieve it? ie clicking on a button?

Comment: it will be clicking a button

Comment: charlietfl because the list is built dynamically and sorting it between two columns hence the built list is invalid HTML that is why I am trying to make it a valid HTML. Actual code is too long for me to put here.

Comment: Then you still need to fix how it gets dynamically created. Using invalid html can cause unexpected behaviors across different browsers and the elements may not even be inside the outer `<li>` when rendered

Comment: So where is the code that generates it? that's where you need to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take all the `li`s except the first one, you can use this:

```
var els = [];
$("#CommonResults ul li:gt(1)").each(function(){
  els.push($(this));
  $(this).remove();
});
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  ul.append(els[i]);
}
$("#Common_container").append(ul);
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/330juLmn/**